# Find absolute position of objects when only distances are known.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, recreational-mathematics

I have a set of objects `u1, u2,..., un` and an algorithm which gives a R(1000) [1000 dimensional] vector for each object.

```
Table 1
   t1  t2  ... t1000
u1 234 157 ... 92
u2 117 157 ... 39
...
un 234 157 ... 39
```

From this data, I'm calculating hamming distance between these objects:

```
Table 2
row col distance
u1  u2  200
u1  u3  500
u4  u2  200
u4  u3  900
...
```

I want to create a 2D plot in which each object is a point and distance between points comes from `Table 2`.

For that I need absolute positions of these objects in some 2D space. Is there a way to find or simulate absolute positions when only distances are known. If yes, how do I select what to put on `x-axis` and `y-axis`?

Comment: If the points are in 1000 dimensions, there's no reason to think you can represent them in two.

Comment: @Milloupe And satisfy $n\times n$ constraints for arbitrary $n$?

Comment: Unless the $n$ points are somehow coplanar. (dimensionality reduction?)

Comment: @peterwhy points are not coplanar. If I do dimensionality reduction, the distance between the points changes, both order and magnitude.

Comment: @Milloupe The distance in this case is hamming distance. How is it possible to plot all points in 1D? Take this example, 1 and 2 are 100 places apart, 2 and 3 are 500 places apart, 3 and 1 are 50 places apart. How do I place these points in 1 dimension?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't understand it this way, my bad.

Comment: @penguin your example does not satisfy triangle inequality, so the 2D plot you are looking for is not a Euclidean plane.

Comment: @peterwhy I agree, found a general solution to tackle this problem, multidimensional scaling - may work accurately when "euclidean" distances are known
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multidimensional_scaling

Answer (score 1):

Figured out a way to this - Multidimensional Scaling 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multidimensional_scaling

This may work accurately when "euclidean" distances are known. Not sure how much information does it compromise with hamming distances.